# При подключении к Microsoft Access ошибка "Невозможно найти устанавливаемый ISAM."

Tags: c#, ado.net

Ошибка выпадает здесь:

```
dataAdapter.Fill(ds, "BookStore");
```

В чём причина?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public string CmdText =
             "SELECT * FROM BookStore";
            public string ConnString =
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=D:\\Database1.accdb";

            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(CmdText, ConnString);

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                dataAdapter.Fill(ds, "BookStore");
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;

            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: А что такое BookStore? Обычная таблица или ссылка на внешний файл? Не эта проблема случаем: http://jonwilliams.org/wordpress/2014/03/21/enabling-xbase-dbf-support-in-microsoft-office-access-2013/

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight,таблица в БД